# how do I make an unlimited loop that executes once in c++

Tags: c++, loops

I'm creating a game in c++. My current goal is to check the player's health in a forever loop to check if he is dead. While he is, i want it to cout << You are dead. But since the cout << is
in a while statement, checking for the health all the time, the result outputs and executes cout <<
many times. I want it to check for the health forever in a loop, and if the health is < 1, i want it to cout << "You are dead"; only one time. Is there a way to tell the while statement to only execute one time? heres my current while statement:

```
bool gamerunning = true;

while (gamerunning == true) //While game is running...
{
if (health < 1) //If player is dead...
{
cout << "You are dead";
}
}
```

Executing this code outputs "you are dead" a bunch of times. I want it to keep checking for the health in this loop but i want the cout to execute once, so it doesnt repeat the same message over and over again. If you can provide a small example on what to do to stop this, it would be highly appreciated. Thanks so much guys!

Comment: Are you saying, you don't want the game to end if the player is dead?

Comment: Use different game states?

Comment: set gamerunning==false in that if

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to stop the game running when the player is dead, in which case you want this:

```
while (gamerunning == true) //While game is running...
{
  if (health < 1) //If player is dead...
  {
    cout << "You are dead";
    gamerunning = false;
  }
}
```

If not, then you can keep another `bool` that says whether the death output has occurred:

```
bool deadOutput = false;
while (gamerunning == true) //While game is running...
{
  if (health < 1 && !deadOutput) //If player is dead...
  {
    cout << "You are dead";
    deadOutput = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not something like that?

```
bool gamerunning = true;

while (gamerunning == true) //While game is running...
{
   if (health < 1) break
}
cout << "You are dead";
```

If you want to keep your loop you can just add extra bool variable - userDead, make your check only if userDead is false and after writing the output you can set it to true.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
bool gamerunning = true;
bool output_done = false;

while (gamerunning == true) //While game is running...
{
    if ((health < 1) && (output_done != true)) //If player is dead...
    {
        cout << "You are dead";
        output_done = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `bool` to keep track of whether or not it's happened already:

```
bool gamerunning = true;
bool printed = false;

while (gamerunning == true) //While game is running...
{
    if (health < 1) //If player is dead...
    {
        if (!printed) {
            cout << "You are dead";
            printed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

normally you'd have a statemachine....but a simple way is to keep track..

`bool gamerunning = true;
    bool alive = true;`

```
while (gamerunning == true) //While game is running...
{
   if (health < 1 && alive) //If player is dead...
   {
      alive = false;
      cout << "You are dead";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool gamerunning = true;

while (gamerunning == true) //While game is running...
{
    if (health < 1) //If player is dead...
    {
         cout << "You are dead";
         break;
    }
}
```

or

```
bool gamerunning = true;

while (gamerunning == true) //While game is running...
{
    if (health < 1) //If player is dead...
    {
         cout << "You are dead";
         gamerunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to break the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool gamerunning = true;
bool playerDead = false

while (gamerunning == true) //While game is running...
{
    if (health < 1) //If player is dead...
    {
       if (!playerDead) 
       {
           cout << "You are dead";
           playerDead = true;
       }
    }
}
```